# How to fix laggy mouse on Raspi 4?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-buster

Just got a raspi 4B installed raspi os with desktop and the mouse input is very laggy. Why ist that? How can I fix it?

I have tried adding the line below to `/boot/cmdline.txt` but no luck.

```
usbhid.mousepoll=0
```

I have also tried some things:

- using a wireless mouse with a dongle, so I moved the dongle
- tried a wired mouse
- permanently monitoring the temperature of the pi's processor (t < 61°C)
- changed screen refresh rate to 60 Hz
- increased GPU memory to 132

Comment: have you tried more than one mouse? i.e. determine if the problem with the mouse or with the pi

Comment: Thanks for adding the details to your question.